# Is there a breed of rabbit that doesn't grow more than the size of a hand?

Tags: rabbits, pet-selection

A pet shop owner has a litter of tiny bunnies (maybe mini lop/lion head crosses) and she is claiming that they will remain that size into adulthood. She says that they were imported from Holland. Can this be possible?

I had a pet bunny from her shop and it died suddenly a few weeks later. I'm being told that it's because it was too young and was taken from its mother too soon, but the pet shop owner claims that they are 3 months old.

Comment: If you have reason to doubt the word/quality of an animal being offered for sale, shop elsewhere.  Also many shelters have abandoned rabbits available for adoption.

Comment: Related question [At what age can/should a baby rabbit (kit) be separated from it's mother?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/3108)

Answer (score 2):

There are some [Dwarf Rabbit Breeds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dwarf_rabbit) the smallest seem to be Netherland Dwarfs at 2 - 2.5 pounds (0.907 - 1.134 kg). Though one Wikipedia article claims [weights as low as 500 g (1.1 lbs)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netherland_Dwarfs) are possible, not sure I believe this is likely for an adult rabbit.  With [1.5lb to 2.6lb (700 to 1.2 kilos)](http://www.rabbitmatters.com/netherlanddwarf.html) being more likely.

I am not finding any quality reliable references at the moment, but small rabbits usually get to full size in 5 - 7 months, with [large rabbits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flemish_Giant) taking up to 18 months.  Rabbits are old enough to breed at in the [3 - 8 month old range](http://florida4h.org/projects/rabbits/MarketRabbits/Activity8_Maturity.html), and have generally reached 80% - 90% of the full size at this time. Obviously it is important to separate by gender around 4 months, lucky the boys tend (**tendency not a rule**) to mature a bit slower than their sisters.

In Summary it is possible to find a "rabbit that doesn't grow more than the size of a hand". But it is unlikely to be a crossbreed, it would likely be from a dedicated show breeder. The smallest rabbits that come into the organizations that I volunteer with [*(see my profile)*](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/13/james-jenkins) are around 3 - 4 pounds full grown.

Comment: It is more difficult than you might imagine to find quality references on when a rabbit reaches adult size.  In production rabbits it seems that adult size is not a requirement for healthy off spring, and in the companion animals there has not been interest in researching.  If you have a good reference please point me towards it.

Comment: Do you have pictures of said tiny rabbits James?

Comment: @mtanti I do not.  There is definitely room for a better answer on the subject of tiny rabbits.  [see also related on weaning](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/3108)

Comment: The ARBA produces a book called the Standard of Perfection.  It contains detailed descriptions of the standard physical features of each recognized breed, including weights.  [Here is an easy reference page](https://www.arba.net/breeds.htm) that lists the current recognized breeds and their maximum weights though.  There are a few that have no maximum weight listed but it is a rare rabbit that gets over 15 pounds even in the Giant breeds.  I do know of a few Flemish Giants that have been over 20 though.