# Can I put 2 different batches of baby rabbits together

Tags: rabbits

I have 2 does and one buck, both does are pregnant and I want to put them together with their kits. I have 1 huge cage because I want to put the baby rabbits in there with their moms. Will that be okay or will they kill the kits? One of the does is 6 days behind the other.

I am going to separate them, for when they give birth and build nests, for two weeks. After that, will it be okay to put the kits and their moms together?

Answer (score 4):

No, Rabbits are very territorial.  Doe rabbits even more so then bucks.  Each doe wants to have a safe place to have her kits. If you try to put both does together when they are pregnant or have young kits it will likely be a huge battle.  The does will fight each other.  I don't know what they will will do to the kits, but it won't be good.

Related questions

- [Pet Rabbits, Double Pregnacies, and Keeping the Buck in with the Doe](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6581)
- [At what age can/should a baby rabbit (kit) be separated from its mother?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/3108)

Answer (score 1):

I read that a rabbit will sometimes nurse another's babies if they're snuck in with her litter. However, if the two females are both present and both want to nurse, I'm not sure if they'll share the same nest.

I have two does and one buck, I separated the two females and put the male in a separate cage recently because I was worried about them mating. In the short time together out of the cages, it seems the male still managed to impregnate at least one of them. I don't know who gave birth to the first litter, because I wasn't in the room. I separated the two females and put who I thought was the mother with the kits, but within a day the one I removed from the kits gave birth. I don't know what to do, so I connected the two cages again, putting both females back together, and I placed the new litter in with the previous one, in the nest I watched both rabbits build up to the birth. I'm going to buy a syringe and formula just in case I've made a poor decision. I will watch them for any kind of violence as well. I hope you figured out what to do with your rabbits. I read that a syringe and some formula can be used if it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! Please give an update over time

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 does that just had babies. There are 7 in total. The two does have been together there whole life. I have not separated them at all. Even for breeding. Both mothers are taking care of the whole litter as one. There is no issue at all. The babies are doing wonderful.

Comment: How much space do they have in general and do they get additional space regularly?