# What can I do about this injury of my rabbit?

Tags: health, rabbits, medicines, injury, infections

Our Rex rabbit has recently become pregnant and had a miscarriage. She still keeps plucking fur on the back of her neck like she is still making a nest. She has plucked her fur so much she caused a wound and it has become infected. We are currently treating the wound with gauze, self-stick medical tape, and anti-bacterial/infection spray. We are dressing the wound 3x daily. My concern is it is not enough. I have decent medical knowledge regarding reptiles and know decently well about rabbits and breeding. Below is a picture of the infection/wound:

[image: Rabbit Injury]

If somebody could give advice whether dressing the wound and keeping it clean should be enough or if more action is needed that would be fantastic. Thanks in advance!

Info about rabbits:

- There are currently 5 rex rabbits living together.
- There is no aggression between the rabbits: it's not a fight injury
- The injury is located where rabbits normally pluck fur for nesting
- They currently live in a rabbit hutch: half chicken wire/half wooden house

Comment: has there been any pus or other signs of infection? Lethargy, fever..?

Comment: There has been pus after dressing the wounds and pretty lethargic. She has been pretty lethargic since she became pregnant even after the miscarriage. She has not become 'more' lethargic if that makes sense. No fever though. The wound itself is pretty disgusting though. Hard to tell from the photo but it's about the diameter of a quarter.

Comment: To be honest - I would be taking her to the vet to get her checked out.

Comment: Are all 5 of the rabbits girls?  How did she get pregnant? How old are the rabbits?

Comment: We bought the rabbits from an auction. She was pregnant when we bought her. She had the miscarriage I'm assuming from the stress of moving so much. There are 2 boys but they are not sexually mature yet. There are 2 girls (including the 1 listed above) that are sexually mature and 1 that is not. It's hard to determine an age since they were originally going to be killed. They are free from worms and other parasites. They had a rabbit version of wet tail but we were able to fix that.

Comment: If the boys have testicles they are old enough to make babies.  If the one that miscarried could be the mother or sister of one of the boys, and one of the boys is probably the father.  I can only assume the pregnancy is accidental because a mom rabbit should have her own space. Maybe start with reading the questions answers on these two https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/3108 & https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/12208 Additionally 5 rabbits in a single hutch is going to be very tight and stressful. In any case you need at least 3 hutches for 5 rabbits, 5 would be even better.

Comment: @TylerWeaver are you wanting to breed from these rabbits?

Comment: The boys are not yet old enough to make babies. I may have confused by saying a single hutch. It's a homemade hutch that is 8ft long and 6ft wide. It's a very large hutch. Yes we are trying to breed the rabbits.

Comment: Do you know what this is called so I could do more research on it. I had a bunny and when I went to go look at her she had a big wound like that, but I think it was infected and a lot deeper. I went to go check on her the next morning and she wasn’t in her cage and I never knew what happened to her, so I just wanted to know the name so I know how I could’ve helped her.

Comment: I don't know the name of it, sorry. We got pet wound cleaner and bandages and would wrap her up so she'd stop picking at it. It eventually did heal. If it got any worse than what's on the picture, or if more appeared, we were going to take her to a vet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the home treatment of a pet's wound does not heal the injury,  the only followup solution is to take the pet to the vet for diagnosis and treatment.

We have several posts about rabbit living arrangements, a few good places to start reading are below. They may help also

- [At what age can/should a baby rabbit (kit) be separated from its mother?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/3108)
- [Why are my Baby bunnies Dying?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/12208)
- [Pet Rabbits, Double Pregnacies, and Keeping the Buck in with the Doe](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6581)
- [How much space does a rabbit need to live comfortably?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1962)